# Logic Apps Blob overwriting file of same name

Tags: azure-logic-apps

So I am posting the below JSON to a Logic App via a Http-Request-Trigger.

```
{
    "RequestMetaDataValue": {
        "RequestMetaDataUuid": "33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333"
    },
    "OtherStuff": [{
        "OtherStuffUuid": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-1111",
        "OtherStuffString": "peanut"
    },
    {
        "OtherStuffUuid": "e5dceac3-51cb-477b-b3a9-bd08f351cc0e",
        "OtherStuffString": "banana"
    }]
}
```

The Logic App parses the Json, so I can extract the RequestMetaDataUuid value.  In this case "33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333".

I then use a Create Blob (action?) as seen here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage

And how it looks like in my Designer

[image]

So fairly straight forward.

Here's the issue.

If I resend the (same) Json, the blob/file gets **overwritten** in the blob.

For example, if I change

```
"OtherStuffUuid": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-1111",
```

to

```
"OtherStuffUuid": "aaaaaaaa-1111-1111-1111-1111",
```

The blob that originally had "OtherStuffUuid": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-1111" goes to never-never land.  :(

If there anyway to prevent overwrite?

Is there anyway to check that the blob/file already exists (my preference) in the blob storage?

APPEND

Based on an answer, I tried to add the following pre-check.

[image]

Documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#Get_Blob_Metadata_using_path

> Get Blob Metadata using path Operation ID: GetFileMetadataByPath This
>   operation retrieves blob metadata using path.
>
> Required Parameters Blob path string Specify unique path to the blob
>   Key: path
>
> **Returns** Body BlobMetadata Blob metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'Get Blob Metadata using path' action to check for existence of the blob. You can then can use a condition (based on the status code of the get blob metadata action result) to run actions depending on whether the blob already exists.

[image: 'Get Blob Metadata using path action']

Comment: Thanks for reply.........I don't see ActionResult and/or StatusCode.  I only see : 
Blob metadata
DisplayName
ETag
FileLocator
Id
IsFolder
LastModified
MediaType
Name
Path
Size.  (info about it .. if it exists)      I don't see an "isnull" check in the expression window either.

Comment: I appended the question to show screen shots of trying to do what you suggest.

Comment: You would need to switch to code view to tweak the condition: the condition expression needs to be "@equals(outputs('Get_Blob_Metadata_using_path').statusCode, 404)". You probably need to tweak 'run after' of the condition card as well, so that it runs regardless of whether the get blob metadata action succeeded of failed (you can do that via the designer, or just set 'runAfter' to { "Get_Blob_Metadata_using_path": ["Succeeded", "Failed"] } via code view)

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.  I've encountered the add "Failed" before....but I haven't done the non-designer-code-edit part to get the Status Code.  Great tip to pick up.  Thanks again.